# Number of Documents in a LotusNotes view

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-notes

I am working to integrate a Lotus Notes database into Salesforce using Java. However, I am running into trouble for one portion of the project.

The data I am returning to Salesforce gets initialized in the form of:

```
String[][] result = new String[id.length][field.length]
```

id and field are both arrays that I create inside Salesforce and pass as parameters to the Java that handles the web service.

Most views I've had to access have had a unique id to query off of, so it was fairly simple to populate an array of ids that I want to query Lotus Notes with.

However, I ran into a problem with one View that does not have anything available as a unique id. Our solution was to concatenate two columns together as the SF id and just pull the whole View back. This means I just need to tell the results array to be View.NumberOfRecords instead of id.length in size. But for the life of me, I cannot find how programatically pull the number of documents in a view.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I am new to Lotus Notes, and hope to not have to use it again if figuring out simple tasks like this require so much effort.

Comment: Notes is no more difficult than anything else you don't already know. It gets a bad rap, partly because M$ lovers have been painting it that way for years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `getEntryCount()` or `getTopLevelEntryCount()` methods of `View` class.

Comment: Thanks so much! I knew it was something simple. SO is saying I have to wait 8 minutes to accept your answer, but I will asap.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490191/getting-total-view-entries-including-categories-performance-issue

Answer (score 0):

[Mindoo blog](http://www.mindoo.com/web/blog.nsf/dx/17.01.2013085308KLEB9S.htm), source of cutting-edge XPages tips writes about neat trick. Instead of calling getCount/getEntryCount, use [documented](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Domino%20Designer%209%20XPages%20Reference#action=openDocument&res_title=skip_NotesViewNavigator_JavaScript_dd9xr&content=pdcontent) method of ViewNavigator.skip(amount). With big enough parameter it will skip to last entry, returning number of skipped entries = number of all entries. Should be much faster.

Comment: Tried it with a view with 455K documents. `getEntryCount()` first time 8.5 sec, after that 0ms. `createViewNav().skip(500000)` first time 53 sec, after that 23 sec.